# Show the question nearby as you are typing your answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, edits

When I'm answering a question, and my question is the 3rd or 4th answer, I can't see the original question while I'm typing.  I often scroll up to re-read some part of the original question.  Sometimes I even paste the question into the answer box as I'm typing, so that it will be right there for me to read.

I suggest that when answering, the position of the question and the answer edit box should always look the way it does for the very **first** person to answer a question- that is, the question should be directly above the editor.  Then after submitting an answer, it would fall to the bottom, just as it currently does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes please, I often open up a new tab with the question for reference.

Comment: I will typically do the same thing myself.

Comment: That works too... but the fact that you have a workaround indicates that there is a small problem to work around, yes?

Comment: I think the "yes Please" indicates that he agrees with you, Joseph.

Comment: I guess I need a nap. :)

Comment: I was just about to post this question and searched it first. I would really love that feature and I cannot think of why its not there. Mays because of huge posts or the fact posts might get edited while you type (but what does that change?).