# Show question when editing an answer

Tags: feature-request, edits, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display the original question beneath the answer edit form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form)

Somewhat related to [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20049/show-the-question-nearby-as-you-are-typing-your-answer), I think it would be helpful to see the original question when you're editing an answer. Often times I edit my answers to add/tweak code samples, but have to switch tabs/windows to see the question.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if implimented (the original request) that It would apply to both New Answers and Editing answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem in the past, much like the previous request of having to open multiple windows. I'm personally used to it, but being able to see everything from one screen would make things a whole hell of a lot easier all around.